Can a loss be used to offset taxes on profits that are much larger? A question about a passage in "The Intelligent Investor"
From "The Intelligent Investor" Fourth Edition, 1973, chapter 12 - "Things to Consider About Per-Share Earnings" (emphasis mine):

... [Northwest Industries] was planning to write off, as a special charge, not less than $264 million in one fell swoop. Of this, $200 million represents the loss to be taken on the proposed sale of the railroad subsidiary to its employees and the balance a write-down of a recent stock purchase. These sums would work out to a loss of about $35 per share of common before dilution offsets, or twice its then current market price. Here we have something really significant. If the transaction goes through, and if the tax laws are not changed, this loss provided for in 1970 will permit Northwest Industries to realize about $400 million of future profits (within five years) from its other diversified interests without paying income tax thereon.

Is he really saying that 264 million can entirely offset 400 million here? This beats me. It seems possible only with very peculiar tax laws, or there is some elementary mathematical argument that I am missing.

It's more than 50 years ago.... Who remembers what were the tax laws there? But accounting works in mysterious ways, maybe it was in fact true.

He's probably saying that the 264 million dollars would be combined with other tax benefits to offset 400 million dollars in profits.

@PeteBecker Why wouldn't he mention other tax benefits and only talk about "this loss provided for in 1970"?

@TheFootprint -- because he's a bit sloppy.

@PeteBecker is he? Is this a known thing?

@TheFootprint -- well, "lazy" might have been a better description. But, yes, his writing is sometimes incomplete. When he says "the consequences are X" he's right, but there may be more going on than what he's just discussed; the additional stuff isn't pertinent to his point.

@PeteBecker Now some things start to make sense. I've got stuck on similar passages throughout the book and wasted a lot of time, because I am not yet at the level where I can sense if his point is worth understanding or not.

@PeteBecker He's not being sloppy or lazy, he's just plain wrong. If I say "If I had a nickel for every time someone made a ridiculous economic claim, I could buy a cup of coffee", that means "(# ridiculous economic claims)(5 cents)>price of coffee".
It does not mean "(# ridiculous economic claims)(5 cents)+money I already have in my pocket>price of coffee"

There's nothing magical going on here. He's talking about a $264 million tax write-off, in the context of per-share earnings: $35 per share, more than twice the current market price. That's remarkable, and that's what the text is about.
That bit about the $400 million write-off is additional information, but not the primary point of the paragraph. The $264 million is part of that $400 million. There have to be other write-offs to get the amount up to $400 million, but they don't relate to the point about per-share earnings that he's making, so he didn't go into details.

I'm more convinced by your "lazy" explanation in the comments. I mean, why did he go into such detail on the 264 million and not once mention other loss sources, which would have made the write-off seem even more impressive? From more than 2 times the earnings to more than 3 times!
